# How to configure EVM in IntelliJ with Solidity plugin

Tags: solidity, evm, solc, compiler, intellij

There is a related question/answer from 5 years ago but back then the plugin only provided syntax highlighting.

Now, I know I can compile from the solidity file opened in IntelliJ, clicking on a play/run green arrow in the gutter.

My problem is:
After I click on the arrow ("Run ContractName.functionName") I get a "Edit Configuration" window.
with an error at the bottom ("Error: EVM is not configured").
I'm encouraged to click on a FIX button.

When I do that I get another window to configure Solidity.
And here I can't introduce good values.

[image]

I don't know what to put on the EVM path.
If I put the Solc path (/usr/local/bin or /usr/local/Cellar/solidity/0.8.14/bin)
I get "No Solc installation found".

I don't know how to configure.
I also have truffle and ganache installed but I preferred to compile directly from IntelliJ.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be very useful to have such option but I am afraid it will not be possible (or at least not reasonable).
For me all options that are available under:
**Edit Configuration → Error: EVM is not configured → Fix** lead in one way or another to EthereumJ related stuff.
Unfortunately EthereumJ on [github](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj) is marked as deprecated and latest commit is from 20 May 2020.
I assume it may be possible to somehow build its codebase yourself and set EthereumJ VM path to generated artifact but still you would be ~2 years behind in terms of Ethereum evolution...